# Catch no entity database error by the exception type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to put the code to sleep if the database is down. Everything is working fine. I am checking if the database is available by catching an exception then I am checking for the exception message. Is there any way for example the exception type, error number .....

```
if (ex.Message == "The underlying provider failed on Open." || ex.Message == "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)")
{
       CheckConnection();
}
```

Comment: What type of exception are you trying to handle, we can't see that...

Comment: I would like to catch whenever the Entity database is not available